# how to put icon after the word skip

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to put a icon after the word skip
put it always appears in the top left corner.

Example: Skip>

```
Text(text = buildAnnotatedString {
        append("")
        val skipText = stringResource(id = R.string.skip)
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
        ) {
            append(skipText)
        }
        Icon(Icons.Filled.ChevronRight, "chevron right")
    },
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
    modifier = Modifier
    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
    .padding(bottom = 50.dp)
)
```

Comment: I believe that the fact that you can use `Icon` inside `buildAnnotatedString` is a bug. In fact, it only adds the `Icon` as if you put it right after `Text`. Only functions declared in `AnnotatedString.Builder` are gonna build the string. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70911714/3585796) for some reference on how you can implement such design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`inlineContent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/InlineTextContent) attribute to insert a Composable into text layout.

```
val inlineContent = mapOf(
    Pair(
        "icon",
        InlineTextContent(
            Placeholder(
                width = 12.sp,
                height = 12.sp,
                placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.AboveBaseline
            )
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.CheckCircle,"",tint = Color.Red)
        }
    )
)

Text(
    text = buildAnnotatedString {
        append("")
        val skipText = "Skip text"
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)){
            append(skipText)
        }
        appendInlineContent("icon", "[icon]")
    },
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(bottom = 50.dp),
    inlineContent = inlineContent
)
```

[image]

Comment: Then how to put a margin between text and inlinecontent? Not giving a padding